# Php mobile validation

Tags: php

I want to simply validate 10 digit mobile no. but it is not working.
can anyone plz tell me what is wrong in this code? 
thanx in advance

Here is my code

```
    <?php

          $nameError=$emailError=$phnoError=$addressError=$companyError=$genderError="";
    $name=$email=$phno=$address=$company=$gender="";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
       $valid = true;

      if (empty($_POST["name"])) {

        $nameError="name is required";
          $valid = false;
       }
      else{
            $name= test_input($_POST["name"]);

             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                $nameError="Only character and white space allowed";
             }
        }

       if (empty($_POST["email"])) {        
     $emailError = "Email is required";
     $valid = false;
     } else {

     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailError = "Invalid email format";

      }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["phno"])) {

        $phnoError="phno  is required";
        $valid = false;
         }



        else{
            $phno= test_input($_POST["name"]);

              if (!ereg("^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$", $phno) ) {
            $phnoError="please enter 10 digit Mobile Number";
            $valid = false;

         }

          }

         if (empty($_POST["address"])) {

         $addressError="address is required";
         $valid = false;
         }
        else{
             $address= test_input($_POST["address"]);
                }
                 if (empty($_POST["company"])) {

                $companyError="company name is required";
               $valid = false;
                }
                else{
                  $company= test_input($_POST["company"]);
                     }

                 if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
               $genderError = "Gender is required";
           $valid = false;
            } else {
           $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
             }

               if($valid){
                header('Location: database.php');
   exit();

}
}

     function test_input($data){
        $data=trim($data);
        $data=stripcslashes($data);
        $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;  
            }


?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
<span class="error">* required field.</span></br></br>

Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name1" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<span class="error">*<?php echo $nameError; ?></span></br></br>

Email Id: <input type="text" name="email" id="email1" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailError;?></span></br></br>

phone no:<input type="number" name="phno" id="phno1" value="<?php echo $phno;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $phnoError; ?></span></br></br>

address:<input type="text" name="address" id="address1" value="<?php echo $address;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $addressError; ?></span></br></br>

Company:<input type="text" name="company" id="company1" value="<?php echo $company;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $companyError; ?></span></br></br>

Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender1" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="Male") echo "checked";?> value="Male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender1" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="Female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
<span class="error">* <?php echo $genderError; ?></span></br></br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="error" value="submit">

    </form>



</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/", $phno) ) {
    $phnoError = "please enter 10 digit Mobile Number";
    $valid = false;
}
```

Comment: Even though in this case code-only answer is something that might satisfy the questioner, you should still include some explanation on your answer. The main part to explain is of course the regular expression used and why it works.

Comment: sir i still getting the same problem.
sir i just need to check if the no is 10 digit then it do no show any error message. but if the no is less or greater than 10 digit then it show me "please enter 10 digit no".

Comment: Now mobile no problen is solve but when i submiting the form it is not storing into the database...plz help me